# Missing Step in Python Goolge API Oauth2 from terminal can't skip browser need

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-api

i'm able to create an oAuth 2.0 credential in my project. 
I download the credentials file to the same folder. 
Run my code and in the termnial it asks me to visit a URL to verify. I do that (copy and paste) however it redirects to localhost and fails.

Not sure how to get by this step so I can use my API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch Google API, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314547/error-redirect-uri-mismatch-google-api-how-to-fix)

Comment: @Jescanellas I ddn't think so but I'll try it out.....